# How to fetch media files (images/video) only from my IPhone camera?

Tags: ios, swift, phasset

The fetch assets method allows getting all media assets - taken from IPhone camera and downloaded from the internet.

```
PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: fetchOptions)
```

How could I get only assets taken by my camera?

Comment: Did you try the ph asset collection subtype? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetcollectionsubtype

Comment: @Wouter Yes, and in the different configurations, but can't find any setup which returns only images from the camera, without shares from messengers or by Airdrop.